# Regex check returns false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex for the following pattern:-

> 1234,4321;5678,8765;1234,4321;5678,8765;1234,4321;5678,8765;

`/[0-9]+,[0-9]+;/g` or `/\d+,\d+;/g` doesn't seem to work in JavaScript.

Output:-

false

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "1234,4321;1234,4321;1234,4321;1234,4321;";
  var patt = new RegExp(/[0-9]+,[0-9]+;/g);
  var res = patt.test(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}

myFunction()
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: define **"doesn't seem to work"**  pls. Regex.test returns a `boolean` indicating if there are matches or not. it doesn't return actual matches. Use `String.match()` for that

Comment: Does the pattern always end with `;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the RegEx /^([0-9]+:[0-9]+,)*$/ solves the problem. ()star makes sure the pattern matches every time.

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "1234,4321;1234,4321;1234,4321;1234,4321;";
  var patt = new RegExp(/^([0-9]+:[0-9]+,)*$/);
  var res = patt.test(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}

myFunction()
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your just need one correction. i.e., pass the global flag `g` as a second parameter to RegExp constructor.

```
function myFunction() {
var str = "1234,4321;1234,4321;1234,4321;1234,4321;";
var patt = new RegExp(/[0-9]+,[0-9]+;/, 'g');
var res = patt.test(str);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

Comment: OP's code is just fine. [Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/wc6g4c9z/). global flag is retained